# sinon stubs not working in nodejs tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am writing the tests for the `Invoicer` module.

I am having two issues with my tests. The first one is that the emails are still being sent despite having stubbed the `emailjs` module (first test) and the second issue is that my second test timesout after 2secs.

I don't understand why?

Could anyone help me out with this?

`Invoicer`

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('underscore');
var request = require("request");
var email = require("emailjs");


exports.Invoicer = function (url, context) {

    // set-up our transporter object with credentials
    var transporter = email.server.connect({
        user: 'Pinoquio',
        password: 'sdlfkjlj',
        host: "pinoquio@gmail.com",
        port: 444,
        tls: true
    });

    // read html file for email
    fs.readFile('./email.html', function(error, data){

        if (error) {
            context.done(new Error("There was an error reading the file ---> %s", error.message));
        }

        data = data.toString();

        var template = _.template(data);

        // request data from url
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
                context.done(new Error("There was an error with request --> %s", error.message));
            }

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                if(typeof body === "string") {
                    var _body = JSON.parse(body);
                }

                var populated_html = template(_body);

                var mailOptions = {
                    text: populated_html,
                    from: 'hick <hick@beta.hick.com>', // sender address
                    to: '<mario@hick.com>', // recipient
                    subject: 'Invoice'
                }

                transporter.send(mailOptions, function(error, message){
                    if(error){
                        context.done(new Error("There was an error sending the email: %s", error.message));
                    }else{
                        context.done();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

`Tests`

```
var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var testedModule;
var fs = require('fs');
var email = require('emailjs').server.connect();
var expect = chai.expect;


describe('invoicer successful process', function () {

    var nock = require('nock');

    var ResponseOptions = {
        username: "Peter Pan",
        user_address_line_1: "Never Never Land",
        user_address_line_2: "Tree-house 99",
        user_post_code: "E4 9BY",
        delivery_address_line_1: "Hook's Boat",
        delivery_address_line_2: "Dock 69",
        delivery_post_code: "SE2 4C",
        order_number: "234234234",
        order_date: "20/12/2090",
        dispatch_date: "20/12/2090",
        items: [
            {
                product_name: "Fairy Dust",
                brand: "Airy fairy",
                quantity: 5,
                total: 2000
            },
            {
                product_name: "Pirate Sword",
                brand: "Pirate's Bay",
                quantity: 8,
                total: 2000
            }
        ],
        grand_total: 4000,
        user_email: "peter@flyaway.com"
    }

    var mailOptions = {
        text: "Hello World",
        from: 'hick <hick@beta.hick.com>', // sender address
        to: '<mario@hick.com>', // recipient
        subject: 'Invoice'
    }

    var scope = nock("http://beta.hick.com")
        .get("/orders")
        .reply(200, ResponseOptions);

    var sendMailStub, readFileStub, url, contextDoneSpy, server;

    before(function () {

        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.autoRespond = true;

        sendMailStub = sinon.stub(email, "send");
        readFileStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile');

        testedModule = proxyquire('../index.js', {
            fs: {readFile: readFileStub},
            email: {send: sendMailStub}
        });

        url = "http://beta.hick.com/orders";
        contextDoneSpy = sinon.spy();

        readFileStub.withArgs('./email.html').callsArgWith(1, null, 'file1');

        sendMailStub.withArgs(mailOptions).yields(null, contextDoneSpy);

    });

    after(function () {
        fs.readFile.restore();
        email.send.restore();
        server.restore();
    });

    it("readFile and successful context.done were called", function (done) {
        testedModule.Invoicer(url, { done: function () {
            contextDoneSpy.apply(null, arguments);
            expect(readFileStub).has.been.called;
            expect(contextDoneSpy).to.have.been.calledWithExactly();
            done();
        }});
    });
});

describe("fs.readFile", function () {

    var readFileStub, url, contextDoneSpy, server;

    before(function () {

        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.autoRespond = true;

        readFileStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile');

        testedModule = proxyquire('../index.js', {
            fs: {readFile: readFileStub}
        });

        url = "http://beta.hick.com/orders";
        contextDoneSpy = sinon.spy();

        readFileStub.withArgs("Hello world").callsArgWith(1, new Error("Error reading file"), null);

    });

    after(function () {
        fs.readFile.restore();
        server.restore();
    });

    it("returns error", function (done) {
        testedModule.Invoicer(url, { done: function () {
            contextDoneSpy.apply(null, arguments);
            expect(contextDoneSpy).has.been.called.and.calledWith(new Error("Error reading file"));
            done();
        }});


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve the second issue first by placing `return` after the `context.done(new Error....)`

fs.readFile('./email.html', function(error, data){

```
if (error) {
    context.done(new Error("There was an error reading the file ---> %s", error.message));
    return;
}
```

and by passing in a valid file name in my test, as opposed to just a random string:

```
   readFileStub.withArgs("./email.html").callsArgWith(1, new Error("Error reading file"), null);
});

after(function () {
    fs.readFile.restore();
});
```